# Delphi THTTPRIO A Certificate is required for client authentication

Tags: delphi

I am trying to send soap requests to a web service using THTTPRio. Requests seem to go through fine until a certain amount of items are added to the XML.

For example I am sending account numbers so that I can retrieve the balance for each account from the web service, sending up to 150 accounts works as expected, once I move to 151 accounts when the request is send it fails asking for a certificate.

I have contancted the people in charge of the web service and they tried to change the authentication to Basic Auth (Username/Password), they have also sent me a SSL certificate, but the issue persists.

I have added the auth details to the HTTPRio.HTTPWebNode.Username and HTTPRio.HTTPWebNode.Password

I have also added the certificate name/issuer/serial number to the HTTPRio.HTTPWebNode.CertName/CertIssuer/SerialNum. Still no luck

I have read that the issue may be that HTTPRio check the current user store for the certificate and that it may not find a certificate installed for the local machine so I also tried to install the certificate for the current user, unfortunatelly that also didn't solve the issue.

When copying the request from the BeforeExecute of HTTPRIO and running it through Postman it all works as expected, if I enable SSL cert on Postman and provide the cert I was given I get the expected result, at the same time I can just keep the SLL cert disabled and have no issues in postman.

Any idea of what I could do in this scenario where the service works up to a number of items in the XML and requires a cert after, am I missing something in the HTTPRIO properties maybe?

Thanks in advance for the help

Comment: Strange. You could try sending the request with another HTTP component.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Oliver for the suggestion unfortunately I am quite new to SOAP requests and WSDL and I used the HTTPRIO component as that is what the WSDL call was requesting. Also I am short on time as this is work related and needs to move ahead, for now I have split the requests into smaller chunks but it would be great if I could find out what was causing it.